# color attribute of css is not working

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of the following classes for h2 and a:link but its not working. Here what I did so far:

```
    <div id="post-1132" class="post-1132 news type-news status-publish hentry category-news">
          <h2><a href="http://domain.com/index.php/news/news9/" title="Midwest premium rises to 6-month high">Midwest premium rises to 6-month high</a></h2>
            <div class="post-info">
              <span class="date published time" title="2015-12-05T09:27:58+00:00">December 5, 2015</span>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <div class="summary"><p>NEW YORK  The Midwest aluminum premium has yielded another bump following the Thanksgiving break, 
                reaching its highest level in more than six months. AMMs assessment of the spot P1020 premium rose to 8.75 to 9 cents 
                per pound from 8.5 to 8.75 cents per pound previously. The premium last topped this level on May 
                <a href="http://asc100.com/index.php/news/news9/">Continue Reading &rarr;</a></p>
                <a class="moretag" href="http://domain.com/index.php/news/news9/"> Read the full news article</a></div>
            </div>
    </div><!-- post -->

.hentry h2 {  
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 0px;
  color: #125CAA;
}
div.summary a:link{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #125CAA !important;
}
```

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `:link` from there:

```css
.summary a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #125CAA;
}
```

This should work without `!important`. It is not a good idea to use `!important`.

The reason for why it is not working for you is, you might have visited the link, so `:visited` will only be working.

Add this in your CSS:

```css
#single #primary {float: left; width: 75%;}
#single #sidebar {float: right; width: 20%; margin-top: 150px;}
```

The [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) will provide you with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more for reaching the a tag inside the h2 as follows:

```
.hentry h2 {  
font-size: 18px;
height: 0px;
}
.hentry h2 a {   color: #125CAA; }
div.summary a:link{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #125CAA;
}
```

As you can see in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGyqpw), the text in the h2 tag is in red but no the a inside it due to the inherit rules

Comment: Yes he did, you can see a red text which is the content of the text node of the h2 and the link in the color #125CAA as desired.